# Replacing backslashes with commas in Bash

Tags: text-processing, sed, bash-script

I tried writing a script in which I am reading through a file line-by-line. I am supposed to replace a backslash (\) with a comma (,).

The input file is as follows:

```
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1\A,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION2\B,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1\C,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1\D,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1\E,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1\F,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1\G,5
```

The piece of code I've written is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat $1 | while read -r line
do
ln=$(echo $line | xargs | sed 's/\\/,/g' )
echo $ln
done

echo Done!
```

When I run `./script.sh file.csv`, I am getting following output:

```
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1A,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION2B,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1C,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1D,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1E,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1F,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1G,5
Done!
```

Whereas, I am expecting an output as follows:

```
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,A,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION2,B,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,C,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,D,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,E,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,F,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,G,5
Done!
```

I also tried replacing `sed 's/\\/,/g'` with `tr "\\" ","`, but it is not helping. Any modifications needed?

Comment: That's what `tr`'s for: `tr '\\' ,`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
# cat a.txt 
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1\A,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION2\B,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1\C,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1\D,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1\E,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1\F,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1\G,5

# sed -e 's/\\/,/g' a.txt 

1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,A,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION2,B,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,C,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,D,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,E,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,F,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,G,5
```

Comment: @Abhishek - Dhanyawaad!

Comment: @MandarShinde Pleasure is all mine.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a better way of writing the same script you tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line
do
  echo "$line" | sed 's/\\/,/g'
done < "$1"

echo Done!
```

Of course, the whole thing could just be simplified to

```
#!/bin/bash

tr '\\' , < "$1"
```

Comment: `tr` all the way - thats the quickest way to do it for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure your shell doesn't eat those backslashes when pushing them to `sed`:

```
sed 's/\\/,/g' <<\BS
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1\A,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION2\B,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1\C,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1\D,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1\E,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1\F,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1\G,5
BS

#OUTPUT#

1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,A,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION2,B,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,C,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,D,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,E,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,F,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,G,5
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do it natively in bash - using either `${line/\\/,}` to replace the first occurrence or `${line//\\/,}` to replace all occurrences of `\` in `${line}` (equivalent of `sed` with the `-g` modifier):

```
while read -r line; do 
   echo "${line//\\/,}"
done < file.csv
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,A,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION2,B,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,C,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,D,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,E,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,F,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,G,5
```

Answer (score 2):

Here comes an awk solution,

```
$ awk -F'\' '{print $1","$2}' file.txt
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,A,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION2,B,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,C,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,D,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,E,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,F,5
1,2,3,WORKSTATION1,G,5
```